# How can I create an exe for .NET Core console applications?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to get the `exe` file from a .NET Core console application, but I only get a DLL output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create the exe running the following command, if required for release or debugging purposes, assuming also a 64bit Win10 OS, you could do the following :)

**Debugging**:

```
dotnet publish -c Debug -r win10-x64
```

**Release:**

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

Comment: ***...where win10-x64 is one of [runtime identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)*** should be added